# Extract data from iframe pdf file

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, pdf.js, drawrectangle

i have simple website with pdf viewer by pdf.js and what i want to do is draw rectangle via mouse and get text from iframe pdf file to text field. None of my code work properly

I did almost every options from web but still no result, only drawing rectangle in js work

Comment: Is the PDF file in an iframe? If so, are your website and the PDF on the same host name?

Comment: Yea, same catalog all script is in index.HTML and second file in folder i my PDF file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: <iframe id="pdf-js-viewer" src="autozapis1.pdf" title="webviewer" width="700" height="800"></iframe>